# Set the css property of a class based on its visibility property using CSS only

Tags: css

I have a set of div whose visibility is set to either hidden or visible. Based on this css visibility property i need to add the css property on those div, like

```
<div class="div-class" style="color:#ff0000; margin: 0px 10px; visibility:hidden;">
    [Block of Code]
</div>
```

Now i need to define the following in style.css file.

```
.div-class:visible {top:10px;left:50px;}
.div-class:hidden {top:0px;left:0px;}
```

Is this possible???

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve doing so?

Comment: why would it matter where the div was when it is hidden ?

Comment: Not possible. But you can use a class to control both positioning and `visibility`.

Comment: You can do it with Javascript/Jquery . But CSS not sure :)

Answer (score 2):

yes with css attributre selectors you can do it
try the below css:

```
.div-class[style*="visible"] {  
  color: green; 
}  

.div-class[style*="hidden"] {  
  color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not "really" possible.

I mean it's ill thought by design in the first place.

Even Vamsikrishna's solution might not work as expected.

If you set the `overflow` property to `hidden` via javascript or inline styles, the `.div-class[style*="hidden"]` rule will apply since the `style` attribute will contain the `hidden` string.

Moreover , setting inline styles on html elements is bad practice itself in most cases.

I suggest you try and learn css principles a little more.

I'd do the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="div-class div-hidden">
    [Block of Code]
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div-class {color:#ff0000; margin: 0px 10px; top:10px;left:50px;}
.div-hidden {visibility:hidden;}
.div-class.div-hidden {top:0px;left:0px;}
```

Then you can use javascript to toggle the "`div-hidden`" class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something using attrchange - a jQuery plugin ,
like this:

1. Add "attrchange" script into HTML page like
2. In Javascrip catch event

var email_ver_input = $("input#email_ver_input.verifyInput");
email_ver_input.attrchange({
trackValues: true,
callback: function (event) {
if (email_ver_input.is(":visible")){
$("#inputcode_wrap").show();
}
}
});